# how to send data with file upload to the server

Tags: java, android

I am currently uploading file in android. Now I want to send some data lets say and ID with that fileupload. So I will deal with this ID on the server side. Here is how I am uploading file. This code works perfectly fine.

Here is the code

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri, final String imageName) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imageName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String upLoadServerUri = "http://www.example.com/android/fileupload.php";
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sourceFileUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
        return 0;
    }

    try { 
        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

         // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
             dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
             bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
             bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
             bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
        if(serverResponseCode == 200){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     //tv.setText("File Upload Completed.");
                     if(fileData(globalUID, imageName)) {
                         Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                 }
            });
        }
        //close the streams //
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    dialog.dismiss();
    return serverResponseCode;
}
```

Comment: Could you be explicit about the question.  I'm not sure what you want to do that you are not doing.

Comment: I want to POST key/values with this file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can write query string onto output stream.

```
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write( yourQueryString.getBytes( withSpecificCharset ) );
```

And in the server `php` script you can read query parameters as usual.

```
$param1 = $_POST[ "param1" ];
```

You can refer to [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2793150/revisions)'s [community wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/767881) on [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests). It discussed with examples on HTTP Post with file upload and query parameters.